# iterating an enum with a while loop

Tags: java, enums, while-loop

Sorry for the very noob question.
Let's suppose I have an enum like so

```
public enum MyElementType {
TYPE_ONE,
TYPE_TWO,
TYPE_THREE;
}
```

When I want to loop over this enum, I always see this solution:

```
for(MyElementType type: MyElementType.values())
{
//do things
}
```

I wonder if there exist a viable solution with the while loop.
Seraching around I see that Enumeration interface exposes the method
    hasMoreElements()
but I don't know how to link the things together.
Any advice?

Comment: Why do you want a while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use a while loop rather than the for-each you more typically see?

In any case, it's pretty simple

```
Set<MyElementType> elements = EnumSet.allOf(MyElementType.class);
Iterator<MyElementType> it = elements.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    MyElementType el = it.next();
    // etc
}

// or
Iterator<MyElementType> it = Arrays.asList(MyElementType.values()).iterator();
```

Comment: I want to use a while loop because I want to check another condition in the while statement to decide wether to continue the iteration or not (and I really don't like to use the "break" inside a for). Anyway, the thing made me courious and it seemed to me a good chance to learn something I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html